# array.every() fail - is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I encountered a problem.

If I delete the part with `options.every(){}`, everything works perfectly.

I want to check if all options are active.
If all options are active, I want to deactivate them and if all options are not all active I want to keep options active + activate the clicked option.

I would try to do this check methode: with `options.every(){}`, but it gives me errors like:

> options.every is not a function at btn.onclick.

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much!

```
let btnsClassOfProducts = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-class="products"]');
let btnProductsAllProducts = document.querySelector('span[data-class="allProductsProducts"]');



function sortingUiEffect(options, all) {
  options.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.onclick = function() {

      if (all.classList.contains('active')) {
        all.classList.remove('active');
        btn.classList.toggle('active');
      } else {
        btn.classList.toggle('active');
      }

      let verify = options.every((btnx) => {
        btnx.classList.contains('active');
      })

      if (verify) {

        options.forEach((btn) => {
          btn.classList.remove('active')
        });

        all.classList.add('active');

      } else {
        btn.classList.toggle('active');
      }

    }
  })

  all.onclick = function() {
    options.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.classList.remove('active');
    })
    all.classList.add('active');
  }

}

sortingUiEffect(btnsClassOfProducts, btnProductsAllProducts);
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html so we can see the entire picture.

Comment: `[...options].every`

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:prototypejs]. Are you using that library? Or is this mistagged? (Since it hasn't been updated since 2015 and I hadn't heard of anyone using it for even longer I suspect the latter).